# UIImagePickerController loading bar/pop up after use

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am currently working on my iphone app. While I'm taking a picture with UIViewController, I work on it (some rotation, transformation, whatever), then I show the result of the transformation, right after taking this picture.

The problem is that while cliking on the "Use" button, the app is working on the picture for a few seconds, but the user doesn't know anything about it, and keep clicking on the "Use" button 'cause he thinks it didn't work.

So I would like to show a pop saying "Loading..." or a loading picture, just to let the user know that the "use" button worked.

But my pop-up only shows up right after the work is done, and not before...

Here is my code.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    UIAlertView *waitingFor = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Chargement" message:@"Votre photo est en cours de traitenment, veuillez patientez quelques secondes." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [waitingFor show];

    myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    /*My transformations*/

    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use MBProgressHUD it is so easy to use & display the message. Download MBProgressHUD.h & m class

from here: `https://github.com/cokecoffe/ios-demo/tree/master/MBProgressHUD`

Then just add these two classes in ypor project & use like below:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *) Picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info 
{
    hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
    hud.delegate = self;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading\nPlease Wait";
    dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 0.05 * NSEC_PER_SEC);
    dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void)
                   {
                      myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
                      [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
                   });
}
```

and then check. You should import this in your .h class `#import "MBProgressHUD.h"` also declare `MBProgressHUD *hud;` & make property `@property (nonatomic, retain) MBProgressHUD *hud;` in .h class & also `@synthesize hud;` in .m class.

Comment: Got an issue with the "hud.delegate = self;" line. I got an error saying "Assigning to 'id<MBProgressHUDDelegate>' from incompatible type 'BothView *const __strong'". BothView is my UIViewController class.

Comment: Declare <MBProgressHUDDelegate> in .h file....where you declare your delegates....

Comment: Here, like this in .h file @interface ViewController : UIViewController<MBProgressHUDDelegate>.....

Comment: Thanks, I've done it, but it doesn't seem to work. Actually, it doesn't do anything, I've done what you said, by changing my 3 firsts lines in my method by yours.